# How to declare main class for Scala in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm trying to implement the simplest bits of coding in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.1 with Scala plugin, scala-sbt 0.13 and jdk-1.8. Here's the code:

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}
```

It compiles with an error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
```

In Run/Debug configurations the're is a warning 'Class HelloWorld not found in module ...'

Could you bring some light on that?

Answer (score 1):

Right click the Scala project in IntelliJ IDE and click "Open Module Settings". Now, click "Global Libraries" and see whether Scala libraries are present there. If there is no Scala libraries, please add it.

Please refer the below snapshot.

[image]

Comment: They're Java JDK in SDK's, scala-sdk-2.10.4 in Global Libraries. In Modules the're 
Source Folders
src\main\java
src\main\scala
src\main\scala-2.11 and so on

Still an error.

Comment: Can you please try the same hello world in Scala REPL and check whether it works?

Comment: And from sbt - console